# How to disable touch of previous layout

Tags: android, layout

I've android layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <Layout
        android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.test.console.LoginFragment"  />

    <Layout
        android:id="@+id/transperent_fragment"
        android:name="com.test.transperentFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/body_texture"
        android:alpha="0.2"> />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: If I touch on transparent layer still login button gets clicked. So how to avoid login button click after touch on transparent layout]

If I touch on transparent layer still login button gets clicked. So how to avoid login button click after touch on transparent layout

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are 2 options to make your bottom layout non clickable:

1. Make your bottom layer (or button) non clickable by adding attribute `android:clickable="false"`
2. Make your top layer clickable by adding attribute `android:clickable="true"`, then touch wouldn't pass to lower layers.

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

use **wrap_content** for login button

```
<Layout
    android:id="@+id/login_fragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.test.console.LoginFragment"  />

<Layout
    android:id="@+id/transperent_fragment"
    android:name="com.test.transperentFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/body_texture"
    android:alpha="0.2"> />
```